# assembly language conversion of program from hexa decimal to decimal with scoring for loop

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture, simulator

A hexadecimal number provided by user for 5 times in loop should be converted into to Decimal number, This should provide us with display the correct answer incase the input provided is wrong and gives a final score at the end of loop

```
model small
.stack 100H
.data

hexnumber db 10,13,'Enter a hex digit: $'
continue db 10,13,'Do you want to continue?: $'
errormsg db 10,13,'Illegal character, Enter 0..9 or A..F: $'
decimalnumber db 10,13,'In decimal it is: $'

.code
MAIN PROC
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

continue:   ; start of loop
            mov ah,9
            mov dx,offset hexnumber
            int 21h
            mov ah,1
            int 21h
            mov cl,al

legal:      ;Compare input to see if its less than 00H if its greater 
            ;than AAH
            cmp cl,00h   ;cl < 00h
            jl  end_if   ;yes, error msg

            cmp cl,AAh   ;compare cl >AAhh
            jg  end_if   ;yes, error msg

            jmp finally

end_if:               
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,errormsg ; print error message
            int 21h

            jmp continue ; reenter a hex number

            jmp legal    ; jump back to test
finally:                                               
            ; determine if number ; 0..9 and display
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,decimalnumber ; display decimalnumber
            int 21h

            mov ah,2
            mov dl,cl    ;display number          
            int 21h

            ; determine if number a..f and display
            mov ah,9 
            lea dx,decimalnumber  ; display decimalnumber
            int 21h

            mov ah,2
            mov dl,cl  ; display MSB for 'A' to ;'F'              
            int 21h

            mov ah,2
            sub cl,11H       ; displayLSBfor'A'to'F' 
            int 21h
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,continue     ; display continue 
            int 21h
            mov ah,1
            int 21h
            mov bl,al
            cmp bl,'Y'           ;bl = Y
            jne eoj              ;no, end

            je continue          ;yes, loop back

eoj:        ; return to DOS prompt
            mov ah,4ch
            int 21h
main endp
end MAIN
```

I am really unsure why the above code is not executing correctly and would need some help or guidance further , conversion from hexadecimal to decimal is done but repeating it in a loop and calculating the score is something which is not coming up

Comment: What's the point of `jmp legal` since the `jmp continue` right before it is unconditional? Seems like dead code to me.

Comment: @Michael You rightly pointed it out, `jmp continue` is used so that the loop can be implemented for 5 times. Should this be removed?                                            
 P.S I am pretty new to this  coding

Comment: I'm really sure the code executes correctly, i.e. the assembler and computer do what you asked them to do. But I have some doubts why you wrote some things there and why there's some other missing.. For example there's no way to loop 5 times in total. Those two `cmp` checking `al` for 00h and AAh and using signed-interpretation are dubious as well (`al` can be less than 0 only for values -128..-1, so for those you jump to "end_if", for +0..+127 you then check against AAh = (-86) and jump to "end_if" for greater values, but every value +0..+127 is greater than -86, so you will have error always

Comment: If you are new to assembly, like you spend few lessons over it, and you are trying your first code, it's normal to struggle this much, but make sure you have some good book/lectures available and some examples, and study for a while theory, then study for a while working examples, then try your own code, and rotate around that... and learn to use debugger, it's absolutely vital.. You are just at the beginning, so everything may look complicated, but actually assembly is sort of very simple in "machine" way of thinking, if you are precise and familiar with basic math, you may really like it...

Comment: "conversion from hexadecimal to decimal is done" - not really, I don't see it... I see some very hard-coded instructions which may eventually do something for few values, but it's not like you can enter any character from 0 to F (as hexadecimal digit), and it will output on screen string "0" to "15"... maybe start with that, put some ASCII character '0'..'F' directly into `cl` and just try to output "0".."15" according to it. No loops, no input.. just conversion + output. If it works, add input. After that works, add input validation. After that try to loop 5 times... Tiny steps...

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks so much, will start looking the way you stated.